# how to send table data to mysql using php

Tags: php, html, sql, database-design

[image]

Student No is a not a auto increment primary key.And there are 10000 users in our database but they are using their own key.We have another method to restrict the duplicate id.I't ok. I was able get all checkbox values using jquery/ajax .Now i want to send all data to the db.So how i create the database tables for this ? I think i want to create 2,3 tables for this ?

I used this jquery to get all the selected/no selected checkbox values

```
   var serialized = $('input:checkbox').map(function() {
   return { name: this.name, value: this.checked ? this.value : "false" };
 });
```

Comment: What tables do you want to create?

Comment: Are you trying to create tables, access your database via PHP, or do something in your Javascript? For best results, we may want to focus on one question at a time.

Comment: I want to create mysql database tables to insert data ?

Comment: @DiliniWasana: You do?

Comment: But the problem is there are 661 array values send from above table.SO how to use 1 one table.if create so many tables how to acchive it ?

Comment: What does the check box represent. Will there be more than one year? PS FEB and Economics...

Comment: no database will update annually

Comment: So you are throwing all the data away on Jan 1st each year. No one will ever want say April to March? you didn't say what the checkbox represent, please don't say course date. A display (though some sort of calendar / date planner would be more intuitive, as data entry? Bad idea on many fronts.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, what is "Piyumix"? It's hard to name a table when you don't know what you're dealing with.

```
schedule
-------
id
id_student
id_subject
date (month?)

subjects
--------
id
name

students
--------
id
name
```

Comment: piyumix is a 234 student name

Answer (score 1):

to be more organized you need

```
    Schedule Table

    scheduleId int primary-key
    classId int
    month date
    value bool

    Class Table

    classId int
    className varchar


   Student Table

   studentId int
   studentName varchar

   StudentSchecdule Table

   tablestudentScheduleId int
   studentId int
   scheduleId varchar
```